# Why is this Codecov report saying that I've reduced my coverage when I don't believe I have?

Tags: code-coverage, codecov

I'm finding CodeCov reports hard to read at times *and are potentially misleading/providing incorrect information*.

**I'm hoping someone could confirm/deny this assertion.**

With this example PR, it's saying that I'm making things worse when I can't see how?

#### Current scenario.

**PR**: `Dependabot wants to bump a Nuget package from 3.0.12 -> 3.0.14.`

[image]

Ok. so this report is saying that the entire project is:

- 46% covered
- we've dropped -23.9%
- it was originally .... 69.9% in the previous commit??

OK, let's look at the diff.

[image]

So this diff says: 1 file only. and it's .. "untracked" ? (not sure what that means).

So with this one file it saying my *coverage* is now dropping by 24%.

Let's look at the commit.

[image]

OK, so this is THE ENTIRE PR. It's just a version number change. *no other files* in the PR.

Now let's go back and see what Codecov is looking at....

[image]

- `an21ad` is the latest commit on `origin/master`. so it's `HEAD`.
- `b3d5da6` is the PR.

ok.. so that's kewl.. but why is it saying the change is so massive for code coverage loss?

Now look at this ...

[image]

and

[image]

wait what? It's saying:

- I have *more than* 99 difference changes between my PR and `origin/master`?
- I have 69 files changed between my PR and `origin/master`

But my commit is only ONE file!

Alright, let's look at one of these random files which is supposedly 'different':

[image]

OK, I really don't know how to read this change. It's saying that these two lines have changed but they really haven't changed.

Can anyone please explain what is Codecov doing/thinking?

I was under the impression that this commit **should not change** the coverage at all.

SIDENOTE: I'm using `flags` so I'm *hoping* that isn't messing things up.